# Invoke a agenda-view integrated with a calendar

Tags: org-agenda, calendar

Usually, I check the agenda-view with a calendar as:
1. M-x org-agenda
2. invoke calendar by strike "c"

at this moment, the focus stay on the calendar
[image]

How could combine the two process? 
If C-c a a to invoke a agenda-view, a Day-agenda integrated with a calendar will be invoked and keep the cursor on the agenda's time-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can advice `org-agenda` to open the calendar and move the cursor back to the agenda. The second advice closes the calendar when you press q in the agenda.

```
(advice-add 'org-agenda :after
            (lambda ()
              (when (equal (buffer-name)
                           "*Org Agenda(a)*")
                (calendar)
                (other-window 1))))

(advice-add 'org-agenda-quit :before
            (lambda ()
              (let ((window (get-buffer-window calendar-buffer)))
                (when (and window (not (one-window-p window)))
                  (delete-window window)))))
```

Comment: What does the underscore "_" do in `(lambda (_)
              (when (equal (buffer-name)`??

Comment: In this case nothing. I removed it. Thanks. Where is `general-advice-add` defined? I don't have that.

Comment: general-advice-add is a compiled function defined in general.el.

A drop-in replacement for advice-add.

Comment: This would require additional installation. I would suggest keeping `advice-add` for simplicity.